# How do I track down the origin of the alt text on a particular image?

Tags: images

I am trying to change the alt text of a particular image on my homepage.  [Here is the page](https://www.horizonhomes-samui.com/), and this is the [image in-question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54eeP.jpg).  Something is causing the alt text to display as 'Horizon Residences,' and I want to edit it.  I've ensured that the media file in the WP back-end has my desired alt-text ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZrqy.jpg)).  Also, when I add the image to the page in the WordPress back-end, I've ensured that the alt-text is my desired text ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC36L.jpg)).

Any thoughts on how to track down the origin of this mysterious alt text?

To check if any templates have the current alt text hard coded, I used grep to search through my child theme files for the term 'Residence.’  But that search did not return anything.  I also tried searching for the string ‘alt,’ but couldn’t see anything relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Leftover javascript from the parent theme?

Comment: @CKMacLeod could be.  Through some grep-work, I managed to ascertain that this image is added to the page via a particular plugin, "Toolset Types."  I've posted to their forums to see if I can make some more headway with the origin of this alt text.  I'll update back here when I do.

Comment: Plugin would have been the next guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was right under my nose.  Right there in the WordPress editor was the relevant line of HTML code (placed there by the plugin "Toolset Types"):

```
<a href="http://horizon-residence.com/">[types field="horizon-residences-banner" alt="Horizon Residence condominium" title="Horizon Residences" size="full" align="left"][/types]</a>
```

It was there that I could change the title, and in-turn, the alt text (since the title was overriding the alt text).